# how can i store value in button at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have a problem i have some dynamic button.and i want to store integer value in that.

and get that value on that click event of that button how can i achieve it

thanks in advance
 shashank

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dtCat, "PK_CATEGORY_ID IN(" + categoryIds.ToString() + "0)", "PK_CATEGORY_ID", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

foreach (DataRowView rr in dv)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(rr[0].ToString() + "------------" + rr[1].ToString());

    Button b2 = new Button();

    //b2.Name = rr[0].ToString();
    b2.Name = "";
    b2.Height = 200;
    b2.Width = 200;
    b2.Margin = new Thickness(0, -100, 0, 0);
    b2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    b2.Content = rr[1].ToString();
    b2.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Pink;
    b2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(b2_Click);
    btncanvas.Children.Add(b2);
    Canvas.SetLeft(b2, b2.Width * i);
    i = i + 1;
    MessageBox.Show(rr[0].ToString());
    b2.Tag = rr[0].ToString();

}


void b2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button clicked = (Button)sender;

    categoryname = clicked.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property is probably what you want.

You are already using it in your example, but just have:

```
b2.Tag = integerValue;
```

Then in your click handler use [`Convert.ToInt32(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325173(v=VS.71).aspx) method to get the integer value back:

```
int retrievedValue = Convert.ToInt32(clicked.Tag);
```

Comment: @SHASHANK - I've corrected the code. I was typing without access to Visual Studio ;)